# Failed to load resource with Less, using cg-angular yo generator

Tags: angularjs, less, yo

I used [`cg-angular-generator`](https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular) to start off my Angular app. Then I installed [`bootstrap-material`](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)

However, when I run `git serve` as per the documentation, I get errors in my console that give little clue as to what's causing them. For example, the error says it's happening in `less-1.6.2.js:7379` but I looked in that file and there isn't even a line 7379. THe last line is 136.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
[image]

Comment: (set less to [development mode](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-setting-options) to get human-readable error messages...). If you look closer to the `material.less` URL you'll notice what the error is (`http://bower_components/...`).

Comment: (And btw., since your project is `grunt`-based anyway consider to use `grunt-contrib-less` instead of client-side Less script. Loading and compiling all those files (it's ~70 for Bootstrap only) in browser is a waste of time.)

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for these tips